Error after scanning qr code for whatsapp-web.js
My whatsappweb bot started having problems this week.
C:\pinkmeupwabot\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221
            throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                  ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:5:95
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\pinkmeupwabot\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\pinkmeupwabot\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async Client.initialize (C:\pinkmeupwabot\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:323:9)

I tried changing the lib and puppeteer versions but without success, the error remains.
I took a look at the lines that indicate the error but my expertise didn't allow me to get that far.
Could anyone help?

Please share your code as a [mcve]. Thanks.

What fixed this error for me was changing my webVersionCache inside the client definition:
    client = new Client({
        authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
        puppeteer: {
            headless: true,
            args: [ '--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu', ],
        },
        webVersionCache: { type: 'remote', remotePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.2412.54.html', }
    });


yes it's working. but what is the reason not working in Localwebcache? any idea.?

Probably something related to the version, Local Cache gets the latest version available and remote cache you can set an specific version

where can I change this code??

for me it doesn't work, because of timeout when load the page https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.2412.54.html, I think because of slow internet.
What I did, Manually load the page, then save it internally under apache ,then change the link locally, finally, it works.

Wow!! I almost gave up on my little project. Thanks

Not working any more

The above solution worked for me, but the problem return back again. So, the l found a solution for the problem throw guthip link https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/2789#issuecomment-2035236279   ,don't forget to change the webVersionCache : { type : 'none' }
